# Конвейерная лента Unity 2D UI

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

Как можно сделать бесконечное движение текстуры на UI Image? Делаю подобие конвейерной ленты. Как можно осуществить подобное? Пример на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Две картинки под маской или написать шейдер.

Comment: Благодарствую !